# Getting the maximum date of a complex property

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular $http, I have a model retrieved from a database. Its a Forum object that has Topics. Each topic has many Posts.

I am displaying a grid with showing |Topic Description|Count of Posts| Latest Post|

I have the first two working but I am not sure how to get at the data from the latest post (last column). A Post has a DatePosted property. I want to show the latest Post with info about the poster and the header etc.

Would this be a custom filter or is their a better way.

```
<div ng-controller="forumCtrl">

<h3>{{forum.ForumDescription}}</h3>
<h4></h4>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Topic</th>
            <th>Threads</th>
            <th>Latest Post</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="topic in forum.Topics">
            <td>{{topic.TopicText}}</td>
            <td>{{topic.Posts.length}}</td>
            <td>{{Math.max(topic.Posts.PostDate)}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use a filter. When you get the data from the http response, find the latest post of each topic and set it to `topic.lastestPost`.

Comment: Some sample code would be good...

Comment: Getting there. I added $scope.Math = window.Math but the above is showing NaN

Comment: By the way, Mr administrator, I put Angular in the title for the very reason that I am looking for an Angular solution. Why was it taken out?

Comment: Thanks ExpertSystem. The filter options works. Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the `orderBy` filter in the view, or have a function in the `$scope` that takes a `Posts` array and returns the latest Post,  e.g.:

```
<!-- Approach 1 -->
<td>{{(topic.Posts | orderBy:'PostDate':true)[0].PostDate}}</td>

<!-- Approach 2 -->
<td>{{latestPost(topic.Posts).PostDate}}</td>

/* Approach 2 */
$scope.latestPost = function (posts) {
    return posts.reduce(function (latest, current) {
        return (current.PostDate > latest.PostDate) ? current : latest;
    });
};
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/QzR2U/)**.

---

<sub>**Notes:**

1. You could alternatively define and use your own filter.

2. The above implementation are demos and do not take into account corner-cases, e.g. empty `Posts` etc.</sub>